# GlideAjax in UI Page with DIRECT flag enabled

Tags: servicenow

I am relatively new to ServiceNow, and I am building some UI pages where I basically do not need any of the SN structure except for **Glide Ajax** (I need to get data from a Script Include).
The problem is that when I select "Direct" the Glide Ajax functions are not available any more in the client script.

Does anybody know if this is possible to achieve? I searched everywhere without success.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you check "Direct", it omits all ServiceNow specific JavaScript and CSS. "GlideAjax" is ServiceNow specific JavaScript.

If the data that you are pulling back from the Script Include is static (meaning that you can pull it when the UI page is loaded) then you can probably do it inside an "evaluate" block in the HTML section of the UI page. You could have your Script Include return a JSON object as a string and store it in a variable. Then you could have your client JavaScript parse that variable. I am not a Jelly expert, so I would be curious to know if it works.